# Why do I get a gap between this tab list and content pane in IE6?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a tab list using an unordered list and CSS. This looks fine in IE7, Chrome, FF, but not in IE6. In IE6, it renders with a gap between the tabs and the content pane and I am struggling to find out why.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ptl_tablist">
  <li><a href="#">Tab One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab Two</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">Tab Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab Four</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="ptl_tabcontent">
Content here: <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt; }

/* Remove bullets */
.ptl_tablist { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* Grey border around inactive tabs */
.ptl_tablist li { border: solid 1px #BBB; border-bottom-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; }

/* Block anchors, grey background, wide padding */
.ptl_tablist li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEE;
    padding: 2px 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Black border around selected tab */
.ptl_tablist li.selected { border-color: #000; }

/* Selected anchor */
.ptl_tablist li.selected a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

/* Yellow background for hovering over inactive tabs */
.ptl_tablist li a:hover { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFF70; }

/* White background for hovering over active tab */
.ptl_tablist li.selected a:hover { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF; }

/* Content under tabs. Clear floating tabs. Pad and border. */
.ptl_tabcontent { border: solid 1px #000; padding: 10px 3px 3px 3px; clear: both; }
```

**jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/s7yZw/1/

Comment: If you're still supporting IE6, you're ruining the internet for everybody! Or at least 98.5% of the people!

Comment: If you're still supporting IE6, you deserve all the hell you get!

Comment: I wish I could ignore it but it's for a client who still uses it as a standard. They'll eventually move up... I hope. I'm developing for modern browsers but fixing gross layout errors in IE6.

Comment: You have to ignore it! It's your duty as webevangelist! We must bannish the IE6's and 7's! I'm very passionate about that =)

Comment: I strictly refuse to support IE6 for any commercial project. If your client insists on you supporting IE6 and, worse, you _agree_ to it, then you're only letting yourself in for a **world of hurt**. Don't do it. Explain to them why it's not a good idea, and then get yourself out of this dangerous and precarious situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange the clear:both on the .pt1_tabcontent for a zoom:1;

```
.ptl_tabcontent { border: solid 1px #000; padding: 10px 3px 3px 3px; zoom:1; }
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat on supporting IE. My company still has a few Financial Institutions whose IT departments haven't cleared the upgrade for IE yet so we have a few legacy contracts for IE6. Thankfully we aren't accepting any new work in IE6.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. What does zoom do to pull the content pane up? (I'll need to put this class in my IE6 sheet though.)

Comment: It triggers the hasLayout property for the element to be true. It's only supported in IE so you can put it in your standard css shee and it won't have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

Float the tabs (LI) left, and the A's too. Then use clearfix on the UL.

Comment: OMG I can't believe I'm enabling you supporting IE6! I hate myself for it! Vote this answer down!